# How to use appsettings.json in another project or class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a property in the appsettings.json that I want to use in another project, for example, I have the API project and a class library, in the API project I have the appsettings.json and in the class library I have a class in which I need to use a property of that **appsettings.json**.

Right now what I have is the following

> Startup.cs

```
 services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration)
                .AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppConfiguration>>().Value);
```

AppConfiguration.cs

```
public class AppConfiguration
    {
        public string SecretKey { get; set; }
    }
```

> UserLogic.cs

this is the class that is located in the class library

```
 public class UserLogic
    {
        private static AppConfiguration _settings { get; set; }

        public UserLogic(AppConfiguration settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public static string AuthenticateUser(UserCredentials credentials)
        {
            return _settings.SecretKey;
        }
    }
```

the code is test, since I'm testing, but what I want to do is use that SecretKey in this class but without having to make an instance of it, that's why the static method, the problem is that when I access the method of this way **UserLogic.AuthenticateUser(null)** and sends me an Object reference, since the _settings variable is not being set

Comment: You need to post your question in English language.

Comment: I have already corrected it

Comment: You have a dependency on AppConfiguration object and you don't want to create an object of it. That's how it doesn't work, I hope you know that. May be instead of Dependency injection via constructor, you should make the static property as public and  set it in the Startup.cs. And the other option is not to use static.

Comment: @Chetan I don't want to instantiate the UserLogic class because it prompted me for an AppConfiguration object, which I don't have

Comment: If you don't want to instantiate UserLogic class object then you should remove the constructor and only keep the static properties and methods. You should assign the static properties value in Startup.cs by doing `UserLogic.Settings = `

Comment: @Chetan It works, but now I would like to know how it would have turned out in case I instantiated the class, how you would have obtained the AppConfiguration object?, if it is not too much trouble

Comment: If you instantiate an object of UserLogic class, that solution is provided in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try injection `IOptions<AppConfiguration>` instead and grab `Value` property from it which should be the object that represents your app settings config - this of course assumes that the `appSettings.json` itself are properly named/formatted to match the structure of your configuration class `AppConfiguration`.

As follows:

```
public class UserLogic
{
    private static AppConfiguration _settings { get; set; }
    
    static UserLogic(IOptions<AppConfiguration> appConfigurationOptions)
    {
        // just in case called with null value, handle validation.
        if(appConfigurationOptions == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appConfigurationOptions));
         }
    
         _settings = appConfigurationOptions.Value;
     }
    
     public static string AuthenticateUser(UserCredentials credentials)
     {
           return _settings.SecretKey;
     }
}
```

That being said, it will be helpful to add the structure of your `appSettings.json` as well.

Comment: The problem is that the code inside the constructor never gets executed, since I access the AuthenticateUser method without instantiating the class

Comment: @IsaacHerrera Static constructor will be executed right before any of its property or method on that class is accessed for the first time. You can take advantage of that. I updated my answer above